# API Call, Copy over Cloud Database over to Local Database

Tags: database, api, web-services, sql, cloud

Wanted to know if there is a way to copy over a cloud database through REST/SOAP Web service Calls to local db instance. For example we would recreate a database Schema in our local database. Then, have the cloud db provider create individual API calls for each table within their cloud db. Then, on our side have a scheduled routine pull the data through web services into a local db instance. Basically copy over a database through API Calls.

I wanted to know if this is a good practice or are there better ways to accomplish this?